# line-through a row in table if the checkbox is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where each row contains document name and there's a checkbox at the start of each row. Some checkboxes are disabled. I want to add `text-decoration:line-through` to that row so that user can easily identify that, that row can't be selected because checkbox is disabled. How can this be done using JavaScript or jQuery?

In below example the row with Doc name 2 should be line-through.

```
<tr>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="doclist" id="someId" value="someId"  onchange="updateList('someId')">Doc name 1
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="doclist" id="AnotherId" value="AnotherId"  onchange="updateList('AnotherId')" disabled>Doc name 2
    </td>
</tr>
```

I tried the below.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function() {
var disabledRow = this.disabled;
disabledRow.addClass("lineThrough");
});
```

CSS

```
.lineThrough{
text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AdBMK/)

```
$('table tr td input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    if($(this).prop('disabled')){
       $(this).parents('tr').css('text-decoration','line-through');
    }
});
```

if you want to work with class

```
$('table tr td input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('disabled')) {
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass('lineThrough');
    }
});
```

As Suggested by [**UweB**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606962/uweb)

`.closest('tr')` is faster than `.parents('tr')`

```
$('table tr td input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('disabled')) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('lineThrough');
    }
});
```

Comment: Replace `parents` by `closest` - it's quicker (it stops traversing the DOM tree on the first match) and more importantly will not select too much in case of nested tables (`parents` will recursively collect all `tr`s all the way up to the root of the document).

Comment: @UweB i added your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:disabled').parent().addClass('lineThrough');
```